# hadoop-env.sh:command not found

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed hadoop but when I type command hadoop version it shows the following error:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 172: ^: command not found
Hadoop 2.7.3
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r baa91f7c6bc9cb92be5982de4719c1c8af91ccff
Compiled by root on 2016-08-18T01:41Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 2e4ce5f957ea4db193bce3734ff29ff4
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you elaborate your query. What command you have tried? When you get such exception. It clearly says there is no such file. Recheck the package.

Comment: and what is this `line 172` in `hadoop-env.sh`? You got your output though.